# Understanding the implementation of a delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have been going to understand advantages of the delegate.I have read that it can be used as an instrument to pass a method as a parameter.For example assume that you have an ordering method that invokes a comparing method as a parameter.So you can choose your desired comparing method as a caller. 
I know and understand the whole logic but when i try to create a simple application according to this knowledge,it doesn't work. Here i have 3 classes and i am going to pass a method as a parameter but i don't know how exactly should i invoke it in my second class.

First:

```
class test1
    {
        public test1()
        {

        }

        public static bool Input()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Second :

```
 class test2
    {
        public test2()
        {

        }

        public void OutPut(Delegate d)
        {
            // Error !!!
            bool a = d();
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The Last :

```
 internal delegate bool Del();
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Del d = test1.Input;
            test2 t2=new test2();
            t2.OutPut(d);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of taking a delegate, you might take a "Func<T>" as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void OutPut(Delegate d)
```

This takes a default delegate that is not what you are looking for. You explicitly declared `Del` for this reason:

```
public void OutPut(Del d)
```

However, delegates are sooo 2001. Use a `Func<T>` for better readability:

```
public void OutPut(Func<bool> d)
```

Comment: You don't have to use the new generic way, but you will find it's less typing and it has better readability, too. But both are equally valid and both will compile.

Comment: @T.shaped: most of C# developers are familiar with signature of `Action`/`Action<>` and `Func<>` delegates, while signature of custom delegates is unknown - developer has to see its definition before use it.